# In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have an app which holds about 100 images. I want to show only 20 images as default, and the rest 80 images i want to make users to pay $0.99 for each image.

what would you suggest to do?

Using product id for each image, doesn't sound really good (80 in-app purchases).

Maybe using just one product id, and check what image user touched, attache the name of the image in NSUserDefaults as NSString, and unlock the image. But there is a problem, i can't use non-consumable product id, so I have to use consumable, right?

Any suggestions will be great!

Answer (score 2):

This would have to be a consumable in app purchase, i.e. tokens/gems etc. Buy x tokens for y price and then z tokens unlocks image i. This is essentially what the consumable in-app purchases are there for. This way in updates you can add more images without having to modify the in app purchase details. And you can vary the prices of different images in a much easier way

Answer (score 1):

Going consumable might not be the best option for what you want. Consumable means a user buys an in-app purchase for a one time use. The way you worded your question, you would like a user to have access to a photo forever, as long as it was purchased once. You would want non-consumable for this, so a user can access the content again if the app is deleted.

Since you have so many images, you can include only the initial 20 images in your app to keep the app size down, and then download the other images as they are purchased. If you target iOS 6+, you can host the images on Apple's servers for free.

Apple Document about in-app purchases: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf